# Asking count frequency in nested list using Python

Tags: python, list, count, frequency

I have a list like this:

```
dttrain = [["sunny","hot","high","false","no"],
    ["sunny","hot","high","true","no"],
    ["overcast","hot","high","false","yes"]]
```

I want to count the frequency by the last index, so for example:

```
sunnny no = 2 , sunny yes = 0, hot no = 2, hot yes = 1.
```

I have tried my own code:

```
c = Counter(x for sublist in dttrain for x in sublist)
```

But this shows:

```
Counter({'yes': 9, 'false': 8, 'high': 7, 'normal': 7, 'true': 6, 'mild': 6, 'sunny': 5, 'no': 5, 'rainy': 5, 'hot': 4,'overcast': 4, 'cool': 4})
```

Comment: What should it show instead?

Comment: sunnny no = 2 , sunny yes = 0, hot no = 2, hot yes = 1 -> like this sir,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the combination of `itertools(product and chain)` and `collections.Counter`

```
from itertools import product, chain
from collections import Counter
{' '.join(k):v for k,v in Counter(chain(*[product(i[:2],[i[-1]]) for i in dttrain])).items()}
```

Output:

```
{'hot no': 2, 'hot yes': 1, 'overcast yes': 1, 'sunny no': 2}
```

Comment: Oh thank again sir, its simple, but can i get the element from the counter?

Comment: @Fian Eka - Please see my Edit

Comment: what a nice code sir, love this. thanks again sir. Wassalamualaikum

Comment: Ye, my hack is pretty convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some untidy code:

```
def iterate_key(name, _counter):
    """
    Iterate a key in a dict, create key if it doesn't exist.

    :param str name: Name of key to iterate.
    :param dict[int] _counter: Dictionary storing count data.
    :return: _counter after iterating key.
    """
    if name not in counter:
        _counter[name] = 1
    else:
        _counter[name] += 1
    return _counter


counter = {}
for sub_list in dttrain:
    key_name = '{}_{}'.format(sub_list[0], sub_list[-1])
    counter = iterate_key(key_name, counter)

    key_name = '{}_{}'.format(sub_list[1], sub_list[-1])
    counter = iterate_key(key_name, counter)

print(counter)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much sir, you save my time. Thanks again. Wassalamualaikum.